# Mobile to PC skype video chat?

Tags: skype, video-calling

I have tried to no end, but Skype for Android doesn't support video chat (unless someone leaked a new version that i haven't seen yet), and I cannot find another video chat app that will connect with Skype contacts. As per the title, I am looking for an app that will allow me to video call from my phone to someone using Skype on their computer. Does anyone know of such an app?

UPDATE: I didn't realize it needed specification, but it does turn out Skype supports video calling for some devices:

> Requirements Android 2.1 operating system and above Video calling
>   supported on the following handsets: Samsung Google Nexus S, HTC
>   Desire S, Sony Ericsson Xperia neo, Sony Ericsson Xperia pro

So to revise my question, **is there an app that allows the HTC EVO to video call from phone to pc?**

Comment: What type of phone do you have? Most of the video calling apps on the market only "officially" support a specific list of devices, Skype being one of them. They don't have a public API, though, so I doubt any third-party clients will support video chat on Skype's protocol (Fring may have previously but it's been blocked by Skype).

Comment: @eldarerathis, HTC EVO, rooted.

Comment: Skype has been systematically denying access to other services/clients that try to use their network.  Unlike Jabber (GTalk) or even MSN, you're not likely to find another client that will work for very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.longislandpress.com/2011/08/05/skype-for-android-video-chat-available-for-majority-of-android-phones/) article describes the next release of [Skype for Android](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.skype.raider&feature=search_result) (v. 2.1) which now supports 17 phones on video chat. The answer before was directing to other services or modified versions of Skype, but this is official, so i thought i'd post it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're rooted, you could also try the newest version of [Google Talk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1062980). It isn't officially supported but I use it on my EVO just fine (I run CyanogenMod 7, though).

[ooVoo](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.oovoo&feature=search_result) has a desktop client and a mobile app, enabling mobile to PC video calls (supports the EVO, but haven't tried it myself).

There also appears to be a [plugin for the Yahoo! Messenger app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.imvideo&feature=search_result) which enables video chat between mobiles or with the PC client. Again, I haven't tried this one myself, but it seems to be the least restrictive about what devices it supports.

**Edit:** It looks like there's [a thread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1148486) where people are talking about Skype with video on the EVO. Might be something helpful there.

Comment: i have the new Google Talk and i've tried ooVoo (didn't like it much on either end), but neither does what i'm asking. i'd like to be able to video chat from my phone to a computer running Skype, as it is by far the most widely used video call service. It's hardly practical to ask everyone i usually skype with to change services so i can call them from my phone...

Comment: [Supported devices for ooVoo](http://www.oovoo.com/Mobile.aspx?pname=MobileOverview).  The EVO's not there but forum posts suggest it might work anyways.  **Edit:** Weird inconsistency! I'd go with what the Market says.

Comment: @Matthew: Weird, the Market lists the EVO as supported (see my link). Although it also lists the "EVO 3G" which...doesn't exist.

Comment: @jlehenbauer As I noted in my comment, you can't Skype without Skype (apart from when apps temporarily find a hole in Skype's access control). Fring used to work with Skype, for example, and is now blocked by Skype.

Comment: would there be a possibility of using the Skype apk from a device similar to the EVO (the Desire S, as are all HTC phones, is very similar to the Evo)? or are they the same app that detect the device when they run?

Comment: @jlehenbauer: You could try that, but I couldn't  honestly say if it would work. **Edit:** Looks like there's [a thread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1148486) where people are talking about Skype with video on the EVO. Might be something helpful there.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called TANGO it allows  video-calling to mobile from a PC. It also supports 3G phones too. Its really good and free worldwide.